Setting up IBM HTTP server audit_log rotate
I found somewhere online that you can set up log rotation for audit_log on httpserver so in my modsecurity.conf i switched logging conf from:
SecAuditLog logs/audit_log

to
SecAuditLog "|/usr/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/rotatelogs -l /usr/IBM/HTTPServer/logs/audit_log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 86400"

when this configuration is applied the file is not created and logging is not in a file that i want and it doesnt even log anything.
When i comment the new config and put back the default one with logs/audit_log it logs again to that file. Im trying to find a way to rotate this log since it can go up to 4 GB in a couple of months which is a lot. Has anyone found the way to do this?
Server version is: IBM_HTTP_Server/8.5.5.22 (Unix)

To be precise IBM HTTP server is not apache. And as this is commercial product did you contact IBM support?

@RomeoNinov yes, you are right, I'm making an edit.. No, i haven't contacted them

What's wrong with using logrotate?
